# how to enable CORS in dojo to connect to Openfire

Tags: apache, tomcat, dojo, openfire, strophe

I am working on a dojo ui using strophe I am connecting to openfire in the apache tomcat server. I get the following CORS error " XMLHttpRequest for https://:7443/http-bind/ required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). "

Any idea of how to enable this using dojo or in apache tomcat or should I do some changes in strophe?

Comment: Have you enabled CORS on openfire? Also if you have self-signed certificate at https://:7443/. Navigate/Go to this page and add certificate as an exception to the browser.

Comment: I have the signed certificate, still I am not able to make the https connection via IE browser

Comment: Is it working with Chrome?

Comment: Yes it works in chrome and mozilla  with http and https.  In IE only http works but https connection fails.  When strophe sends http-bind request, it waits for few seconds with pending and then shows status as aborted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the get call before the post and things started working for me.